# Substitute labels in text for the first letter of the label

Tags: r, regex, substitution

So, I am currently working with texts with labels inside with the R language. The labels go between **, for example:

`text <- "The fir*s double*t day o*f lost* the *w strange*eek"`

I would like to substitute the labels with the first character of the label, so the text would look like this:

`"The first day of the week"`

I have tried this, but it doesn't work. It just erases the asterisks.

`result <- gsub("\\*([^\\*]*)\\*", "\\1", text)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
result <- gsub("\\*([^\\*])[^\\*]*\\*", "\\1", text)
```

You need to capture just the first character after the first *.

Comment: It's unnecessary to escape `*` inside a character class; the regex can therefore be simplified to `"\\*([^*])[^*]*\\*"`.